# Why am I unable to animate my UIView's shadow out?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation, calayer

I want to animate out a shadow on my UIView, so that it starts visible, and by the end of the animation is invisible. I can do the opposite fine, but if I try to fade it out, the animation never occurs, in fact I never see a lick of shadow.

My code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let foo = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    foo.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    applyShadowToView(foo)
    view.addSubview(foo)

    foo.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0

    let shadowAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOpacity")
    shadowAnimation.fromValue = 1.0
    shadowAnimation.toValue = 0.0
    shadowAnimation.duration = 0.5
    shadowAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    foo.layer.addAnimation(shadowAnimation, forKey: "shadowOpacity")
    foo.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
}

private func applyShadowToView(view: UIView) {
    view.clipsToBounds = false
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -5.0, height: 0.0)
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    view.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds).CGPath
    view.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    view.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
}
```

What am I doing wrong here exactly?

Comment: [Working fine for me (I slowed the animation a little though)](https://infinit.io/_/3dNR94K). I guess you could try using a `CATransaction` to update the `shadowOpacity` on the model layer, just to make sure you're not accidently triggering an implicit animation, or update the `shadowOpacity` before you add the animation.

Comment: How odd. You're right. I was testing my animation with the simulator's "slow animations" mode toggled on, and it just completely fails to show. But if I turn that off, it's visible. That's so odd.

Comment: shouldRasterize = true hits me as off. You should be very careful using rasterization with shadows.